# Spring reststemplate - not able to upload file with Large size >3MB file in java, but able to upload small size files

Tags: spring, upload, multipartform-data, resttemplate

Please refer this link, it has full details about issue and code .

https://community.apigee.com/questions/1188/i-am-not-able-to-upload-asset-with-large-size-3mb.html

Thanks bin advance.

Comment: Can you share your dispatcher servlet.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't paste external links like this. It is not convenient for some one who wants to help. 
Try to explain the problem briefly with the effort(Code), you have put in.

Secondly, regarding the problem, By default max size you can send is 128 KB. You need to change this by setting couple of properties in spring.
If you are using Spring boot you can do this like this.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10248KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=1024KB
```

If you are not using spring-boot you need do it like this

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver
      = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(102400);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it. We use spring reststemplate. I'm able to upload file sizes less than 3 mb but more than 5 MB I am getting 500 exceptions, that's is thrown from spring.